# Karma-babel require is not defined, even when not using require

Tags: karma-runner, karma-mocha, karma-babel-preprocessor

I have this:

```
import assert from 'assert';
import foo from './foo';

describe('Array', function() {
```

but when running karma I get the error `require is not defined` even when not using require.

any ideas?

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['mocha'],
    files: [
      'src/**/*spec.js'
    ],
    exclude: [],
    preprocessors: {
      'src/**/*.js': ['babel']
    },
    reporters: ['progress'],
```

Comment: The preprocessors definition (src/**/*.js) will also preprocess third-party libraries, which may cause the problem.

Comment: And how should this config know to transpile the es6 to es5? You need a babelPreprocessor config for this.

Comment: @NielsSteenbeek I have a .babelrc **{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}**, I don't have 3rd party in source.